# react-bootstrap <ToggleButtonGroup> minified error

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

iv`e included ToggleButtonGroup im my project

***i.e*** : `const{ToggleButtonGroup,ToggleButton} = ReactBootstrap`

and i want react to display it, so i included this func in my project.

```
   const {ToggleButtonGroup,ToggleButton} = ReactBootstrap

    const Mainbar = React.createClass({
      render:function(){
        return (
          <div>
         <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="options" defaultValue={1}>

            <ToggleButton value={1}>
               Radio 1 (pre-checked)
            </ToggleButton>

           </ToggleButtonGroup>

        </div>
        )
      }
    })
    ReactDOM.render(<Mainbar  />,document.getElementById("mncontainer"))
```

and i get an error

> Uncaught Error: Minified React error #130;

**must to say that other react-bootstrap like DropdownButton works**

Answer (score 4):

I was also having problems with ToggleButtonGroup and ToggleButton but I was getting an indecipherable error message (React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.)

In the end it was because these 2 components didn't even exist in my react-bootstrap module (was 0.31.1).

I ran `npm install --save react-bootstrap` which installed the latest version (0.31.2) and now the components exist and everything is happy again.